# i upgraded ios version to11.4, when I build my project I am getting this error as AWSCore file not found'AWSCore/AWSCore.h' file not found.Pleasehelp

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services

I upgraded ios version to 11.4, now when I build my project I am getting this error as  AWSCore file not found'AWSCore/AWSCore.h' file not found

## import  and

failed to emit precompiled header 
Please help how to resolve it

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was in the AWSFMDB+AWSHelpers.h file.

It has this import `#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>` which is weird since it's the package importing itself.

I manually deleted this line and rebuilt the project and it worked.

[AWSFMDB+AWSHelpers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p33LW.png)